# Looping through multiple values in json and use one value each time in gatling

Tags: json, scala, session, gatling

I have this scenario:

```
> .exec(http("get print package")
>           .get("url.json")
>           .headers(headers_0)
>           .check(jsonPath("$..shapes[?(@.state=='UNUSED'&& @.assetId==null)].contentPath").findAll.saveAs("plist")))
>         .exec { session =>
>           val plist = session.get("plist").asOption[String]
>           println("EMNGMJGHk  " + plist.getOrElse("NOT AVAILABLE"))
>           println(session)
>           session
>         }
>         .foreach("${plist}","newshole") {
>           exec(session => {
>             def orderRef() = Random.
>             val newshole = session("newshole").asOption[String]
>             //     session.set("contentPath", newshole)
>             println(newshole)
>             session
>           })
```

Now I want to do some POST requests for each value I have in ${plist} and not select the value again and loop through all the values using them only once. When all the values are exhausted, print or escape from the loop.

Comment: any scala/gatling expert please?

Answer (score 0):

You would save you values as part of the session and then iterate them, anyhow, I guess that you don't know that params from Gatling session can be modified using scala functions, please take a look overhere:

https://github.com/enriquezrene/gatling-tutorial/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/enriquezrene/gatlingtutorial/demo05sessionmanipulation/ManipulateParamsFromSessionScenario.scala